# Show Deezer share dialog programmatically

Tags: javascript, deezer

I have tried adding a Deezer share button in my InApp by adding the `dz-share` class and the two `data` attributes like described in the [demo InApp instructions](http://www.deezer.com/app/demo/framework/share):

```
<a class="dz-share" data-id="302127" data-type="album"></a>
```

However, nothing happens when I click my share link. I don't even see the click event listeners or the `dz-btn dz-parsed dz-inapp dz-widget` classes on my link like I see in the demo application. I suspect this is because my app page gets loaded dynamically, i.e. the button element is not initially there.

Is there any way to trigger the Deezer share dialog programmatically with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `DZ.framework.parse()`.
See the docs [here](http://www.deezer.com/app/demo/framework/parse).

Note that you will need your app to be in Deezer to make it work (meaning in the Deezer iframe)